# Normalizing a table to handle row linking

Tags: sql, database

I have a table that stores questions for some exam with the following structure:

- ID: ID of the question. ]
- Number: Question number in the exam.
- Max: Maximum points for the question a student can get.
- Text: The question description.
- isSubQ: Is it a Sub Question? Boolean value.
- part(Optional): What part of the question if it is a sub-question.
- exam: ID of the exam(ForiegnKey).

I feel this structure to store sub-parts of the parent question is redundant and a much better relational schema exists. What is the best way to store sub-questions in other words, what is the best way to link two question rows(one as the parent and one as the sub-part)?

To give more clarity, here is an example. Let's say question 3 on the exam has parts a,b, and c. Part **a** has a different text, and points than other parts(b and c) but is still related to the parent question which is 3.

Comment: for trivial example you would split the model into two tables: question and sub_question.  sub_question.question_id would be the foreign key to the question table and would be used to join the tables

Comment: I would probably keep all questions in one table regardless if they are subs or not. Could have another field for PrimaryID instead of Yes/No field. This will involve a self-join in queries. If a question could be associated with more than one primary, have a second table with fields: PrimaryID_FK, SubID_FK - both fields use the Questions table as data source and retrieve info in query by using the Questions table twice.

Comment: @Kurt, Thank you for your reply. This would require the sub_question table to have the exact same columns as the question table, which in my opinion, is once again redundant.

Comment: @June7 That was what I was thinking, having a boolean column in the question table to check if it is a parent question or not and having another table with two foreign keys. Both are the primary keys from the question table. If it is a parent question, I query the second table and get the sub-question ids from the second column. I'm not sure if that's the best solution either. Is this solution really better than what I already have?

Comment: I advised second table only if a question could be associated with multiple 'primary' questions. And the Boolean field is redundant if you add a PrimaryID field to Questions table. If a record has a value in PrimaryID then it is a subquestion.